# Need a function that is called after a navigator.pop()

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Quite a simple question but I can't figure out the answer.

I need a function that works like

```
  componentDidMount() {

  }
```

after a `navigator.pop`.

Basically just a function that is called when the navigator enters the scene/component that was active before a `navigator.push()`. And is called when it becomes active again after a `navigator.pop()`?

Like an `onEnter()` func that is called every time regardless if it's after `navigator.pop()` or `navigator.push()`.

Comment: How about https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html#ondidfocus ?

Comment: That might work I'll check it out thanks, looks promising!

Comment: Seems that doesn't work with a pop only a push, still searching for an answer.

Answer (score 2):

One solution that worked for me was to pass in a function that I wanted to run when passing props from the first page to the second. Then you can call that function on the second page right before you pop. Here is an example:

```
this.props.navigator.push({
  component: SecondComponent,
  passProps: {prop1: prop1, prop2: prop2, myFunction: this.someFunction.bind(this)}
});
```

and then on the second page:

```
this.props.myFunction();
this.props.navigator.pop();
```

Hope this helps.

Edit: This is probably not best practice to send functions to other components.

Comment: Thanks, it looks a bit hacky, but if it works then I'll go with it.

Haven't found anything else that works.